# Consulta MYSQL desde JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Buenas estoy intentando meter datos que no sean de tipo `String` en mi bd hecha en netbeans, necesito un `double` y un `int`, pero a la hora de meterlos me da error, cosas que no pasa si lo hago con un `String`, dejo aquí el fragmento de mi código que necesita eso:

```
if(codigo==null){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"SELECCIONA Y CARGA ANTES DE GUARDAR");
        }
        else{
        baseDatos bd= new baseDatos();
        Connection cn= bd.Conectar();
        //combersion de tipos
        double precio2= Double.parseDouble(precio.getText());
        Integer numdias2= Integer.parseInt(numdias.getText());

        try {
            PreparedStatement pps= cn.prepareStatement("UPDATE PRESTAMO SET "
                    + "PRECIO='"+precio2+"',"
                    + "NUMDIAS='"+numdias2+"'"
                    + "WHERE NUM_SOCIO= "+codigo);
            pps.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("ERROR AL MODIFICAR ->"+ex);
        }
       bd.cierraConexion();
        cargar(-1);
        }
    }                                    
String codigo;
```

Lo siento si es demasiado abstracto

Comment: Fausto, cuando preguntes recuerda especificar, en este caso el error que obtienes, saludos.

Comment: aparte de las comillas tambien debes de checar en tu bd el campo donde vas a guardar los datos que esten especificados como los vas a guardar aunque si los tienes como varchar no te tiene que dar ningun problema, solo checa las comillas como te lo mencionan en la otra respuesta y person si pongo respuesta pero es que aun no tengo tanta reputacion para poner comentarios :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estas tratando de guardar las variables como `strings`.  Tienes que remover las comillas así:

```
try {
    PreparedStatement pps= cn.prepareStatement("UPDATE PRESTAMO SET "
            + "PRECIO="+precio2+","
            + "NUMDIAS="+numdias2
            + " WHERE NUM_SOCIO= "+codigo);
    pps.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    System.out.println("ERROR AL MODIFICAR ->"+ex);
}
```

Comment: para que usar un PreparedStatement y no usar sus métodos. En este ejemplo sería mejor usar un Statement tradicional. En mi opinión inexperta.

Answer (score 1):

El PreparedStatement tiene una funicionalidad particular, dentro de esta es que puedes poner una interrogación "?" en donde van los parámetros que vas a estar cambiando. Y también tiene métodos específicos para cada tipo de campo, int, String, hasta blobs, y objetos.

En el caso que mencionas, yo lo haría así:

```
PreparedStatement pps=
  cn.prepareStatement("UPDATE PRESTAMO SET PRECIO=?, NUMDIAS=? WHERE NUM_SOCIO=?");

//ahora seteo los parámetros:
 pps.setDouble(1, precio2); //1 porque es el índice de al primera interrogación
 pps.setInt(2, numdias2); //2 porque es el....
 pps.setInt(3, codigo); ///ojo, asumo que código es int, sino cambia al tipo que sea.
```

Después de esto, hacemos el execute:

```
 pps.executeUpdate();
```

No tiene sentido usar un PreparedStatement sin aprovechar sus métodos. En todo caso usar el Statement.